# How can I prevent WebClient from following 303?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I need to authenticate to a web service before using it. I've simulated this with curl successfully, but I can't seem to make it work with `System.Net.WebClient` and I think it's because WebClient Doesn't stop at the 303 response from the server. How can I make it stop?

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection();
    values["username"] = "admin@mysite";
    values["password"] = "swordfish";

    var response = client.UploadValues(loginAddress, "POST", values);
    responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
}
```

After this responseString contains HTML. I just want the credentials/cookie, I don't care bout the actual site.

Comment: So it would seem! Didn't catch that when looking for issues, cheers.